# $wpdb table name

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problem with getting data from database via `$wpdb`:

```
function nadji_sve_statuse() {
  global $wpdb, $leaguemanager;
  $league = $leaguemanager->getCurrentLeague();

  $svi_statusi = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->leaguemanager_person_status} WHERE 1" );
  
  return $svi_statusi;
 }
```

When I replace `{$wpdb->leaguemanager_person_status}` with full and real table name `wp_leaguemanager_person_status`, it works fine - but when user tries to rename database table prefixes to something other, a new problem will surface. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Database_Table_Prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get the prefix of the table, try this:

```
function nadji_sve_statuse() {
  global $wpdb, $leaguemanager;
  $league = $leaguemanager->getCurrentLeague();
  $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'leaguemanager_person_status';

  $svi_statusi = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE 1" );

  return $svi_statusi;
 }
```

Comment: I recommend you to use backtics surrounding table name
``"SELECT * FROM `{$tableName}` WHERE 1"``